# Report is blank when all parameter values selected

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report and I added 2 more parameters - @FreeMealsIndicator and @Bursary in addition to 3 existing ones.

Now, If I select all values for the @FreeMealsIndicator, report looks fine but when I do same for @Bursary I see a blank report.

I am trying to run the query in backend and see data as below:

```
FreeMealsIndicator                         Bursary

16-19 year old learner is eligible         NULL
NULL                                       16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded 
14-15 year old learner is eligible         NULL
16-19 year old learner is eligible         NULL
NULL                                       16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded 
14-15 year old learner is eligible         NULL
14-15 year old learner is eligible         NULL
NULL                                       16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded 
NULL                                       19+ Hardship 
NULL                                       20+ Childcare
```

Any idea why this happens and how can I avoid this?

Comment: All records where Bursary is NULL will be excluded by your @Bursary parameter.

Comment: Even If I select non-NULL records for @Bursary my report shows as blank :(

Comment: In your data sample they are all NULL.

Comment: I will update sample data

Comment: @Steven - Please see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this issue now. I created a dataset using 2 parameters and using specify values(from backend) in parameter properties and report is running fine.